# Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved

Tags: java, android

I'm a student who develop Navigation app for blind person(well that is not important). I try to finish my activity(when a navigation guide is finish) i find this error.

```
08-21 00:36:40.238 18419-18454/? E/Fabric: Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
                                       a.a.a.a.a.e.d$e: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.e.d.code(SourceFile:1355)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.l.a(SourceFile:103)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.l.invoke(SourceFile:90)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.j.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:80)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.j.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:64)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.q.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:155)
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.e(SourceFile:123)
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.c(SourceFile:99)
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.b(SourceFile:45)
                                           at a.a.a.a.h.a(SourceFile:63)
                                           at a.a.a.a.h.a(SourceFile:28)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.c.a$2.call(SourceFile:311)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                        Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                                           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                                           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
                                           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
                                           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
                                           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                                           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1455)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:567)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
                                           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.e.d.code(SourceFile:1353)
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.l.a(SourceFile:103) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.l.invoke(SourceFile:90) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.j.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:80) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.j.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:64) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.g.q.loadSettingsData(SourceFile:155) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.e(SourceFile:123) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.c(SourceFile:99) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.m.b(SourceFile:45) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.h.a(SourceFile:63) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.h.a(SourceFile:28) 
                                           at a.a.a.a.a.c.a$2.call(SourceFile:311) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

08-21 00:36:40.244 18419-18460/? E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings`}

When i debug my application, it's working until finish() line.

application is go into finish(), and next is like this (application stop!!!).

:(((

Someone plz tell me about this error and when it appear?

Comment: you have a socket timeout, network issue, firewall/gratewall  ?

Comment: I found my problem! It was not a socket problem. Thanks to your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and for me it was because the AndroidManifest.xml did not have this attribute set in the application tag:

```
<application android:name=“android:name="io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication">
```